# How can I create a 30 row UITableView, without doing it statically, and accept UITextField input on each row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cocoa-touch

Normally, if I wanted to have a UITextField as a part of a UITableViewCell, I would likely use either a) static rows or b) I would create the cell in the storyboard, outlet the cell and outlet the field to my ViewController, and then drag the cell outside of the "Table View", but keeping it in the scene.

However, I need to create a View where I accept input from 28 various things. I don't want to outlet up 28 different UITextField's.

I want to do this dynamically, to make it easier. So I've created a custom UITableViewCell with a Label and UITextField.

My ViewController has two arrays.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *items;
@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *itemValues;
```

My `cellForRowAtIndexPath` looks something like this...

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    NSString *cellIdentifier = @"ItemCell";
    MyItemTableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (!cell) {
        cell = [[MyItemTableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier];
        [cell.itemValue addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
    } else {
        if (![cell.itemValue actionsForTarget:self forControlEvent:UIControlEventEditingChanged]) {
        [cell.itemValue addTarget:self action:@selector(textFieldDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventEditingChanged];
        }
    }

    cell.item.text = [self.items objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.itemValue.text = [self.itemValues objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

- (void)textFieldDidChange:(id)sender
{
    NSLog(@"textFieldDidChange: %zd", [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row);
}
```

This is proving to be problematic. textFieldDidChange always returns `[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow].row` as 0, as the cell of course, has never been selected. I'm stumped on how I could even find out which row's UITextField has been edited, so I can update the corresponding itemValues array.

Comment: You could just set the `tag` of the textfield to `indexPath.row` and get it back from `sender`...

Comment: You can set "UITextField.tag = indexPath.row" when setting up and then access that to determine which row changed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UITableView has a neat method that converts a point in the tableView to an indexPath, [`indexPathForRowAtPoint:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableView_Class/#//apple_ref/occ/instm/UITableView/indexPathForRowAtPoint:).

First you have to convert the origin of your textField to the frame of the UITableView.

```
- (void)textFieldDidChange:(UITextField *)sender
{
    CGPoint textFieldOriginInTableView = [sender convertPoint:CGPointZero toView:self.tableView];
    NSIndexPath *indexPath = [self.tableView indexPathForRowAtPoint:textFieldOriginInTableView];
    if (indexPath) {
        NSLog(@"TextField at indexPath %@ did change", indexPath);
    }
    else {
        NSLog(@"Error: Can't calculate indexPath");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do this is to just `tag` the textfield with `indexPath.row` and get it back via `[sender tag]` in the delegate method.